# MongoDB update results in error: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, object

I have a MongoDb collection with objects like this

```
 {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63016087246bdba9dec64a30"
  },
  "cards": [
    {
      "number": "1",
      "have": "false"
    },
    {
      "number": "2",
      "have": "false"
    },
    {
      "number": "3",
      "have": "false"
    },
    {
      "number": "4",
      "have": "false"
    },
  ],
  "country": "Ecuador",
  "sigla": "ECU"
}
```

And I want to update only those where `number: "1"`

I'm running this code:

```
const selectedCard = await Cards.findOne({ country: req.body.country, number: req.body.number })
if (selectedCard.cards[req.body.number - 1].have === 'false') {

    await selectedCard.updateOne(
        {
            "cards.$.number": "1",
        },
        {
            $set: {
                "cards.$.have": "true"
            }
        }
        )
```

but I keep getting the `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.` error and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `$` in the `find` clause.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "cards.number": "1"
},
{
  $set: {
    "cards.$.have": "true"
  }
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MYh7a0U8umb) for your reference.

---

In addition, `arrayFilters` is generally more extensible for manipulating array fields.

```js
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "cards.$[card].have": "true"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "card.number": "1"
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qLrmOhu2DCb) for your reference.